# Sliding window average across time axes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large time-series set of data at 30 minute intervals and trying to do a sliding window on this set of data but separately for each point of the day using pandas.

I'm no statistician and not great at thinking or coding for this sort of work but here is my clumsy attempt at doing what I want. I'm really looking for help improving it as I know there will be a better way of doing this, possibly using MultiIndexes and some proper iteration? But I have struggled to do this across the 'time-axes'.

```
def sliding_window(run,data,type='mean'):
    data = data.asfreq('30T')
    for x in date_range(run.START, run.END, freq='1d'):
        if int(datetime.strftime(x, "%w")) == 0 or int(datetime.strftime(x, "%w")) == 6:
            points = data.select(weekends).truncate(x - relativedelta(days=run.WINDOW),x + relativedelta(days=run.WINDOW)).groupby(lambda date: minutes(date, x)).mean()
        else:
            points = data.select(weekdays).truncate(x - relativedelta(days=run.WINDOW),x + relativedelta(days=run.WINDOW)).groupby(lambda date: minutes(date, x)).mean()
        for point in points.index:
            data[datetime(x.year,x.month,x.day,point.hour,point.minute)] = points[point]
    return data
```

run.START, run.END and run.WINDOW are two points within data and 45 (days). I've been staring at this code a lot so I'm not sure what (if any) of it make sense to anyone else, please ask so that I can clarify anything else.

**SOLVED:** (Solution courtesy of crewbum)

The modified function which as expected goes stupidly fast:

```
def sliding_window(run,data,am='mean',days='weekdays'):
    data = data.asfreq('30T')
    data = DataFrame({'Day': [d.date() for d in data.index], 'Time': [d.time() for d in data.index], 'Weekend': [weekday_string(d) for d in data.index], 'data': data})
    pivot = data.pivot_table(values='data', rows='Day', cols=['Weekend', 'Time'])
    pivot = pivot[days]
    if am == 'median':
        mean = rolling_median(pivot, run.WINDOW*2, min_periods=1)
    mean = rolling_mean(pivot, run.WINDOW*2, min_periods=1)
    return DataFrame({'mean': unpivot(mean), 'amax': np.tile(pivot.max().values, pivot.shape[0]), 'amin': np.tile(pivot.min().values, pivot.shape[0])}, index=data.index)
```

The unpivot function:

```
def unpivot(frame):
    N, K = frame.shape
    return Series(frame.values.ravel('C'), index=[datetime.combine(d[0], d[1]) for d in zip(np.asarray(frame.index).repeat(K), np.tile(np.asarray(frame.ix[0].index), N))])
```

The center=True on sliding_mean appears to be broken at the moment, will file it in github if I get the chance.

Comment: Have you seen/tried the built-in rolling mean function?http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.stats.moments.rolling_mean.html?highlight=rolling#pandas.stats.moments.rolling_mean

Comment: Trying to get clear what you're trying to do: you want to average all values within a -45 to +45 day span, but grouped per 24-hour time point. E.g., average all (91) data at 13:00, and separately average all data at 13:30 etc. Because "do a sliding window" is rather undefined: a sliding window of what?

Comment: Also, why the separation into weekdays and weekends? Just logical for the data under consideration, I assume?

Comment: Lastly (keeping separate things in separate comments): is there actually something that does *not* work the way you want it? You don't say it doesn't work, you just like to improve it. In which way? Less code, should run faster, more flexible? Perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be better suited for your purpose then.

Comment: Evert - "and separately average all data at 13:30 etc." is exactly it. I'm dealing with bulk electricity demand data, weekdays and weekends are drastically different. it's pretty slow and I have a hunch that a multi-index would make a lot of operations easier, just wish I could justify making time to learn pandas a bit better/add to it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested in MultiIndexes, check out 
`df.pivot_table()`.  It will create a MultiIndex automatically when
multiple keys are passed in the rows and/or cols parameters.

For example, say you want to pivot the data so there are separate columns for
each weekend and non-weekend 30-minute block of the day; you could do that by adding 
Day, Weekend, and TOD (time-of-day) columns to the DataFrame, and then passing
those column names to pivot_table as follows.

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(values='Usage', rows='Day', cols=['TOD', 'Weekend'])
```

In this format, `pd.rolling_mean()` (or
a function of your creation) can easily be applied to the columns of `pivot`.  pd.rolling_mean(), like all rolling/moving functions in pandas, even accepts a `center` parameter for centered sliding windows.

```
pd.rolling_mean(pivot, 90, center=True, min_periods=1)
```